# Abstract classes, interfaces and Autowired

Tags: java, spring, annotations, autowired

I have the following main class:

```
public class Startup implements UncaughtExceptionHandler {

@Autowired
private MessageListener messageListener;

private static Startup startup;

public static void main(String[] args) {
        Startup start = new Startup();
        start.init(args); 
}

public void init(String[] args) {

    context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
    startup = (Startup) context.getBean( "startup" );
    startup.start(); //here the messageListener is used
}
```

// here goes the main class that calls the method where messageListener is used
    }

```
@Component
public class ProdMessageListener 
    extends AbstractMessageListener implements MessageListener {...}
```

and

```
public abstract class AbstractMessageListener 
    implements MessageListener {...}
```

as well as

```
@Component
public interface MessageListener extends QueueAware {...}

@Component
public interface QueueAware {...}
```

My Spring context uses  to locate all the classes and interfaces. 
However the bean is not recognized and I get:

> No qualifying bean of type
>   [com.ware.messaging.listener.MessageListener] found for
>   dependency.

Any ideas why autowiring does not work?

Comment: where is the autowire?

Comment: compilation  error: MessageListener is extending an interface

Comment: Well, not really. Interface can extend the interface. See [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/616684/java-interface-extends-questions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you know what the problem was? Spring does not seem to autowire static fields. Now everything works.

Answer (score 2):

Just make sure you have added your base package to the spring context configuration like below to allow spring to load all the components into the container

```
 <context:component-scan base-package="pakage1.package2"/>
```

Comment: The implementation class suppose to be a Component not the interface

Comment: The implementation class is ProdMessageListener which is a Component. Is that correct/incorrect?

Comment: Annotating your implementation with @Component and not annotating your interface is usually the right way to set things up. Spring's autowiring will look for a managed bean of a matching type, and your implementation will match for a field typed to the interface. see the below link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10318482/spring-interface-loading